# React Dev Tools with Error "Use Development Build"

Tags: react-devtools

I have a strange behaviour of React Dev Tools in Firefox. I started the days work on a project and also did some profiling -- after some time I got aware, that the React Dev Tools Icon next to the URL got red and the "Profiler" and "Components"-Tab disappeared from the Inspector.

When I press the red React button, there is a popup message "This Website is using a development build. Profiler and Components will appear in the inspector" but they dont.

I would appreciate any helpful advice, for example, is there a place to get log messsages from the React Dev Tools plugin?

Best Regards,
Tobias